# How to make lie detection possible in aiml?

Tags: chatbot, aiml

in aiml i am trying to make bot detect if user has lied there name or not. for instance if a user tells two different names to bot then bot will detect that user is lying by retrieving previous values. here is the code

```
<category>
    <pattern>MY NAME IS *</pattern>
    <template>
     cool name! 
     <think>
         <set name="name"><star/></set>
         <set name="naem">naem</set>
         </think>
    </template>
</category>


<category>
    <that>cool name</that>
    <pattern>MY NAME IS *</pattern>
    <template>
       i thought you are <get name="name"></get>
      </template>
</category>
```

there are 2 scenarios of this code

```
HUMAN: My name is jessop
ROBOT: cool name!
HUMAN: My name is siemens
ROBOT: I thought you are jessop
```

The above scenario works as it is but in second scenario it doesnt make any sense

```
HUMAN: My name is jessop
ROBOT: cool name!
HUMAN: My name is jessop
ROBOT: I thought you are jessop
```

I want to make sure that bot should able to recognize if user has told their name twice which are similar. like this one

```
HUMAN: My name is jessop
ROBOT: cool name!
HUMAN: My name is jessop
ROBOT: I know you are jessop
```

is there any possibility to achieve output like above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using UNKNOWN for the default value of predicates

```
<category>
    <pattern>MY NAME IS *</pattern>
    <template>
        <condition name="name">
            <li><value><star/></value>I know you are <star/>!</li>
            <li value="UNKNOWN"><think><set name="name"><star/></set></think>cool name!</li>
            <li>I thought you are <get name="name"/></li>
        </condition>
    </template>
</category>
```

[image]